# How could I determine the processor architecture of the user?

Tags: javascript

## How could I determine the processor architecture of the user?

I'm making a .NET application, so I'm not skilled with JavaScript. The issue is, when I build the application it produces twelve executeables, based on processor architecture and operating system.

At the moment, I have a GitHub Pages website for the app, and I have a list of downloads. But there's so many that it's even hard for me to find the one for Ubuntu and AMD64.

So far I have this code:

```js
var OSName="Windows";
var suffix = "";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) { OSName="Windows"; suffix = ".exe"; }
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) { OSName="macOS"; }
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) { OSName="UNIX"; }
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) { OSName="Linux"; }
var ProcessorArchitecture = "x86";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("x86_64") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("x64") != -1) {
    ProcessorArchitecture = "x64";
}
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Android")!=-1) {
    document.getElementById("downloads-page").innerHtml = "You can't get Kettle3D on Android devices just now. It works on Ubuntu, Debian, macOS and Windows.";
    return;
}
window.open('./' + OSName + '-' + ProcessorArchitecture + suffix, '_blank');
document.getElementById("os").innerHtml = OSName;
document.getElementById("processor").innerHtml = ProcessorArchitecture;
```

But it doesn't quite work. When I opened this on my phone, the `os` and `processor` sections (which were span elements) showed up as 'Linux' and 'x86', and neither of those are true. It's got Android on an x64 processor. And my friend has an ARM processor, which can't run the x86 software.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You do notice that your code only detect either x64 or x86, don't you? no ARM. Sometimes, the user agent string contains `x64` instead of `x86_64` for x64.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code so that it checks for x64 too. The issue is, on some devices the PA isn't in the user agent string.

Comment: Is it a webpage to redirect to a download link? When it detects Android, it could serve an apk bundled with multiple binaries, or redirect to the store.

Comment: Yes, it is a redirect to a download link, but I didn't make my app for Android. The reason I added that example though is because I can't be sure that it works on all computers if it doesn't work on my phone.

Comment: Then you need to detect Android and exclude it.

Comment: Okay, I've done that now. That'll also fix the whole "We think you're using Linux on an x86 processor" bit.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally posted that twice.